# Creating dynamic, interactive map with QGIS?

Tags: qgis

How can we create an interactive map with QGIS?

I would like to keep aerial photographs as a background layer. When the mouse moves over elements of a shp layer, I'd like them to be highlighted and that a windows shows the information contained in the attribute table of my layers. I would also like that the export is done in a good resolution to be able to zoom in and zoom out dynamically.

---

> Comment peut-on créer une carte interactive avec Qgis ?
>
> je souhaiterais conserver en fond des photos aériennes. Lorsque la
>   souris passe sur des éléments d'une couche, je souhaiterais qu'ils
>   apparaissent en surbrillance et qu'une fenêtre indique les
>   informations contenues dans la table attributaire de mes couches shp.
>   Que l'export permette se fasse dans une bonne résolution pour pouvoir
>   zoomer et dé-zoomer de manière dynamique.

Comment: This question need some more details. I guess the aim is to create some sort of standalone map in a web like interface ?